# Realtime usage tracking of emoji, gifs and hashtags in popular social network sites

Tags: emoji

I had an idea to build an Android app where users can see which emoji, hashtags or gifs is been used in realtime.

Is it possible to track realtime usage of emojis, hashtags and gifs from popular social network platforms?

Comment: Realtime? I doubt that any platform provides an API for that